# ensure that one will/ or without will

Tags: tense, content-clauses

I got two sentences below:

1. *Steve's boss will personally supervise to ensure that they **will complete** an important project by Monday.*
2. *Steve's boss will personally supervise them to ensure that they **finish** an important project by Monday.*

Is it grammatically OK to use *will* in the clause after *ensure* or does it carry a different meaning than the second sentence?

Comment: Since "supervising" is a continuous activity, I would use *will*.

Comment: The fact that `supervising` is continuous is implied in both sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct, however I would rather say:

> Steve's boss will personally supervise to ensure that they **do** complete an important project by Monday.

This is because in this context you are trying to emphasise that `Steve` and his coworkers have got to get the project done. In most cases however, it reads more fluently if you say:

> Steve's boss will personally supervise to ensure that they complete an important project by Monday.

Note that there is a specified deadline for the task `by Monday`.

**OR**

> Steve's boss will personally supervise to ensure that they will complete an important project.

Here the use of `will` implies  that will do the project at some point in the future, but there is no deadline specified yet.